# How can I make a crontab field on Django model

Tags: python, django, cron

I need a field for crontab But I have no logical idea.

I need to send emails with timed tasks from user

I make a Model like this:

```
class crontabMail(models.Model):
    to=models.CharField(max_length=60,verbose_name="To mail")
    mailSubject=models.CharField(max_length=60,verbose_name="Mail Subject")
    mailText=models.CharField(verbose_name="Mail Text")
    startDate=models.DateField()
    endDate=models.DateField()
    cron=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name="Tekrar İçeriği")
```

User will write mail detail on a form and select start date and end date and **User** **select** **timing** for this email.

And I wanna send a JSON like as;

```
   message: [
            {
                to: 'birinci kişi@hotmail.com',
                subject: 'subject',
                html: 'html',
                begin: 'Thu Apr 25 2019 01:08:04 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)',
                end: 'Thu Apr 25 2019 15:08:04 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)',
                repeat: '0 12 */1 * *',
            },
```

How Can I make this? If you have no solution and you have Idea please Share with us.

Have a nice work.

Comment: @Dany, it looks like you are asking how to send emails on schedule, but your question is asking how to make a field. Can you revise the question so it will be more clear what you're trying to do? Also, what andreihondrari is pointing out, there is no need for such introduction - please go straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

To schedule a task in Django, you can use Celery. Here is the doc to implement [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/)

RabbitMQ and Celery have more features and task handling capabilities than Cron. If task failure isn't an issue, and you think you will handle broken tasks in the next call, then Cron is sufficient.